# emacs haskell-mode with cabal project. "Unrecognised target syntax for ` --ghc-option=ferror-spans`."

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, haskell-mode

I'm trying to get **emacs haskell-mode** working with a **cabal** project. Whenever I try to compile or load a file interactively I get the following output in the `haskell-process-log`

compiling  (via (C-c C-c)):

> cabal.exe: No targets given and there is no package in the current directory.

and when loading (via (C-c C-l)):

> cabal.exe: Unrecognised target syntax for ' --ghc-option=-ferror-spans'

---

Set up:
Windows 10,
GHC 8.10.2,
Cabal 3.2.0.0,
emacs 27.1,
haskell-mode 20201120.755

My emacs init file has the following:

```
(require 'haskell-interactive-mode)
(require 'haskell-process)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)

(eval-after-load "haskell-mode"
    '(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'haskell-compile))

(eval-after-load "haskell-cabal"
    '(define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'haskell-compile))
```

With a simple Haskell project, created by running `cabal init`

i.e. with a `Main.hs`:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"
```

and  `my-project.cabal` :

```
cabal-version:       >=1.10
-- Initial package description 'my-project.cabal' generated by
--  'cabal init'.  For further documentation, see
-- http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                my-project
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
-- bug-reports:
-- license:
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              ################
maintainer:          ##################
-- copyright:
-- category:
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  CHANGELOG.md, README.md

executable my-project
  main-is:             Main.hs
  -- other-modules:
  -- other-extensions:
  build-depends:       base >=4.14 && <4.15
  hs-source-dirs:      
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

If I try to compile via `C-c C-c` I get the following in the `haskell-process-log` buffer:

> cabal.exe: No targets given and there is no package in the current directory.
> Use the target 'all' for all packages in the project or specify packages or
> components by name or location. See 'cabal build --help' for more details on
> target options.

If I try to load via `C-c C-l` the haskell process immediately dies prompting me to restart and the haskell-process-log displays:

> cabal.exe: Unrecognised target syntax for ' --ghc-option=-ferror-spans'.

with `'(haskell-process-log t)` and  `'(haskell-process-show-debug-tips t)` set within my init file custom vars this changes to:

```
("Starting inferior `cabal repl' process using cabal ..." "my-project" nil "cabal" "repl" " --ghc-option=-ferror-spans")
-> Prelude.putStrLn ""
   :set -v1
   :set +c
-> :set prompt "\4"
-> :set prompt-cont "λ| "
<- cabal.exe: Unrecognised target syntax for ' --ghc-option=-ferror-spans'.
Event: "exited abnormally with code 1 "
Process reset.
```

Everything works fine in emacs when working on a lone haskell file, i.e. not inside a cabal project.

Compilation and `cabal repl` within the cabal project via command line also works fine.

I've been searching through the docs and googling for a solid day and a half now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: It seems to be something to do with call-process in the emacs source. cabal reports as if it's in the wrong directory even though it isn't. Bizarrely changing the command manually to `cd .  ;  cabal build` fixes the issue and cabal builds happily. See here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63078/bizarre-behaviour-using-call-process-cabal-fails-as-if-it-is-in-wrong-directo

Comment: Update: I tried a fresh install on Ubuntu 20.04 and could not replicate the issue. Meanwhile on Windows 10 the problem persists no matter what shell I set as the default shell in emacs (git bash, cygwin, cmd etc.)

Comment: Update: Downgrading to cabal 2.4 fixes the issue and moving back up to 3.2 restores the problem immediately

Comment: I use Spacemacs. And this is about invoking `cabal run` within emacs right ?

Comment: iirc it was when invoking `cabal run` or `cabal build` among possibly others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Cabal. Specifically in the cabal-install command-line tool that prevented the automatic detection of the primary package on Windows due to Windows denoting drive letters with a capital letter.

I've submitted a pull request:

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/7310